# Where is "create event" on Gmail app?

Tags: gmail, google-calendar

How can I create a calendar event on Gmail android app?

(On the browser this feature is really simple:)

[image]

Comment: Why not just use the calendar app?

Comment: for i'd like to create events tied to particular emails that have necessary details.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Gmail app simply doesn't have that feature. It would be an excellent addition.